# How to add days in a column in Pyspark (with hours, minutes and seconds)

Tags: date, pyspark

I have a pyspark dataframe with 2 columns: "Date_ini", "Days_to_add".
In Date_ini I have a date and Days_to_add contains the number of days I want to plus to Date_ini in order to get Date_limit. 
My code is:

```
df = df.withColumn("Date_limit", expr("date_add(Date_ini,Days_to_add)")
```

And I get this:

| Date_ini | Days_to_add | Date_limit |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2023-10-11 09:03:47 | 10 | 2023-10-21 |
| 2023-10-16 15:08:53 | 10 | 2023-10-26 |
| 2023-10-16 16:17:22 | 6 | 2023-10-22 |

But I want something like:

| Date_ini | Days_to_add | Date_limit |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2023-10-11 09:03:47 | 10 | 2023-10-21 09:03:47 |
| 2023-10-16 15:08:53 | 10 | 2023-10-26 15:08:53 |
| 2023-10-16 16:17:22 | 6 | 2023-10-22 16:17:22 |

Answer (score 1):

You can avoid the unix timestamp back and forth by casting `days_to_add` to `DayTimeIntervalType`
and directly adding it.

```
from pyspark.sql import types as T
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

_data = [
    (datetime(2023, 10, 11, 9, 3, 47), 10, ),
    (datetime(2023, 10, 16, 15, 8, 53), 10, ),
    (datetime(2023, 10, 16, 16, 17, 22), 6, ),
]
_schema = ['date_ini', 'days_to_add']
df = spark.createDataFrame(_data, _schema)

day_field = T.DayTimeIntervalType.DAY
day_interval_type = T.DayTimeIntervalType(day_field, day_field)
days_to_add = F.col('days_to_add').cast(day_interval_type)

df = df.withColumn('date_limit', F.col('date_ini') + days_to_add)
df.show()

# +-------------------+-----------+-------------------+
# |           date_ini|days_to_add|         date_limit|
# +-------------------+-----------+-------------------+
# |2023-10-11 09:03:47|         10|2023-10-21 09:03:47|
# |2023-10-16 15:08:53|         10|2023-10-26 15:08:53|
# |2023-10-16 16:17:22|          6|2023-10-22 16:17:22|
# +-------------------+-----------+-------------------+
```

Answer (score 0):

Yup, finally I used this and worked :)

```
df = df.withColumn("Date_limit", expr("from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(concat_ws(' ', Date_ini, Days_to_add)) + (`Days_to_add` * 3600 * 24))"))
```